# IntelliJ update javadoc

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Is possible in IntelliJ to automatically update javadoc? For example, when I add new method params or throw new exceptions I want them to appear in the existing javadoc comment.

Comment: `Declaration has javadoc problems` inspection provides the corresponding quickfixes.

Comment: So I just have to activate it somewhere?

Comment: Just [type it](http://i.imgur.com/cX1S1P2.png) in settings search.

Comment: Ok, I will test it

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ 2019.2.4 you can open `File/Settings/Keymap/Other` then look for `Fix doc comment` and assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: In v2022.1, I assigned a shortcut but it didn't do anything at first. Your cursor **has to be** on the method declaration line, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get at what you want, but may help others when SO search leads them here. The JavaDoc plugin generates javadoc where non exists. It's a bit dated (intellij 2020.1) and sometimes doesn't work in 2022.1 When it does work -- it's **FANTASTIC!**